# Why did my gulp task stopped generating my css files?

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I use sass (triggered by a gulp task) to generate my css files. I recently formatted my computed and this task stopped working.

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var config = require('../config');

gulp.task('styles', ['copy'], function() {
  gulp.src(config.sources.sass)
    .pipe(sass({ style: config.isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'expanded' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.cssDir));
});
```

This task used to work fine before I reinstalled my OS (Windows 8.1). Now after I run this task there is no visible errors, but no css files are created.

So, the question is:

**Why did my gulp task stopped generating my css files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gulp task is fine.

`gulp-ruby-sass` uses, by default, the gem sass to compile your scss files. Since you recently formatted your computer I bet you installed the last version of Ruby Installer for Windows. I made some tests and I noticed that sass doesn’t seem to work on Windows while using Ruby 2.2.2. The sass gem works just fine on Ruby 2.2 on Ubuntu and OS X.

**If that’s an option, I suggest that you downgrade from Ruby 2.2.x to Ruby 2.1.6 and that should fix your problem.**

In case it doesn’t you could use gulp-debug to check your stream and start from there.

```
gulp.task('styles', ['copy'], function() {
  gulp.src(config.sources.sass)
    .pipe(debug({title: 'Before sass:'}))
    .pipe(sass({ style: config.isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'expanded' }))
    .pipe(debug({title: 'After sass:'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.cssDir));
});
```

If you can't downgrade your ruby version, you could use `gulp-sass` instead of `gulp-ruby-sass`. Gulp sass doesn't require ruby at all, as it uses a wrapper made in node for a C/C++ library - `libsass`.

You could also edit your post and include your `gulp-ruby-sass` version (or your `package.json`) and also your nodejs version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Downgrading from Ruby 2.2 to Ruby fixed my problem! I still don't have reputation to upvote you, though.